# E-tags missing from response headers with rails 3.2 / nginx / phusion passanger

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, nginx, passenger

I have a very simple controller with e-tags:

```
class EtagsController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :require_user

  def index
    if stale?(:etag => current_user)
      render :layout => false
    end
  end

end
```

When I run this in my local development environment, the first request is a 200 with an ETag in the response.  The second request submits back the ETag and I get a 304 response as expected.

However, when this executes in my staging or production environments, there is no ETag in the response.

Here are the request and response headers from my staging environment:

```
Request URL: /etags
Request Method:GET
Status Code:200 OK

Request Headers
Accept:text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
Cache-Control:max-age=0
Connection:keep-alive
Cookie:__utma=169165539.1455374302.1372358226.1372358226.1372358226.1; __utmb=169165539.1.10.1372358226; __utmc=169165539; __utmz=169165539.1372358226.1.1.utmcsr=(direct)|utmccn=(direct)|utmcmd=(none); user_credentials=4ffa15df84112d22434f121eed06c59a5c32cb9ab72cf6bf1e952a3993201b5dec2917a028d20d4b63c70a84c6a290c4d5c4673ce967efec6f139c161850bc37%3A%3A101; _session_id=d21671b70349653406442ee0716633b2
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_8_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/27.0.1453.116 Safari/537.36

Response Headers
Cache-Control:must-revalidate, private, max-age=0
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Encoding:gzip
Content-Length:65
Content-Type:text/html; charset=utf-8
Date:Thu, 27 Jun 2013 18:37:10 GMT
Server:nginx/1.4.1 + Phusion Passenger 3.0.19
Status:200
X-Powered-By:Phusion Passenger (mod_rails/mod_rack) 3.0.19
X-Rack-Cache:miss
X-Request-Id:620c1ab99a1af7b6dde62cee77fc59fe
X-Runtime:0.205884
X-UA-Compatible:IE=Edge,chrome=1
```

Im stumped.  **Why is my staging environment not respecting the ETag in my controller?**

The technologies involved:

1. Phusion Passenger 3.0.19
2. nginx 1.4.1
3. Rails 3.2.13

Thannks

Comment: It seems that rolling back nginx to 1.2.7 fixes this.  Why?  How can I configure later versions of nginix to allow ETags?

Comment: I am seeing the same problem in a PHP app. Unfortunately, in 1.4.1, if gzip is on, the ETag is stripped. 1.2.7 did not have this problem however.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that nginx > 1.3 will ignore the e-tag from your application server if gzip is enabled for nginx.  We didn't find a solution in nginx that would allow us to pass through the e-tags from the application server and gzip the response.  I believe weak e-tags might work for this, but nginx does not currently support them.

Answer (score 1):

Nginx still does not have support for weak etags.  Maybe in 1.7.x:

http://forum.nginx.org/read.php?29,249380,249740#msg-249740

This answer gives a way to have your middleware convert strong to weak etags:

[Weak ETAGs in Rails?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18693718/weak-etags-in-rails)