# Weak ETAGs in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, http, nginx, etag

What is the best way to tell rails to use [weak instead of strong ETAGs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_ETag#Strong_and_weak_validation) when using methods `fresh_when` and `stale?`?

The reason I ask is that [nginx (correctly) removes strong ETAG headers from responses when on-the-fly gzipping is enabled](http://forum.nginx.org/read.php?2,240120,240127#msg-240127).

Comment: The ETag mechanism supports both strong validation and weak validation. They are distinguished by the presence of an initial "W/" in the ETag identifier, so  we can check that while getting that

Comment: @RajarshiDas So, how do you do that? In my controller I have `fresh_when etag: @my_model` which generates a (strong) ETag based on the models cache_key method. Is the answer simply `fresh_when etag: "W/#{@my_model.cache_key}"?

Comment: `etag_matches?(etag) ` to check the etag or `fresh_when("W/#{@my_model.cache_key}")` as you told

Comment: I'm surprised that what Rajarshi Das is suggesting works. Has anyone tried it?

Comment: It's not a direct answer to this question, but it still may be relevant. I found through testing that disabling gzip in my named location in my Nginx config gave me the best performance overall. This is specific to the implementation, but this allows strong etags to persist on requests that reach the Rails app while leaving gzip enabled for other requests. I suspect Rails will give more control over the strong/weak distinction in the future.

Comment: As of April 2014, far as I can tell, nginx still does not support weak etags.  Maybe in 1.7.x says one of the authors: http://forum.nginx.org/read.php?29,249380,249423#msg-249423

Comment: As of July 8, 2014, Nginx 1.7.3 now supports weak etags: nginx.org/en/CHANGES

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I took the code from @grosser's answer and turned it into a Gem:

- https://rubygems.org/gems/rails_weak_etags
- https://github.com/johnnaegle/rails_weak_etags

You can just add this to your gemfile:

```
gem 'rails_weak_etags'
```

And it will be installed into your middleware before `Rack::ConditionalGet`:

```
> bundle exec rake middleware
....
use RailsWeakEtags::Middleware
use Rack::ConditionalGet
use Rack::ETag
....
```

Then all the e-tags generated by rails, either with Rack::ETag or with explicit e-tags will be converted to weak.  Using a patched, or version > 1.7.3 of nginx, will then let you use e-tags and gzip compression.

**RACK 1.6 defaults etags to weak** - this gem is no longer helpful if you upgrade.

Comment: I still do not see how this is fixed, as Rack never removes the "W/" portion and Rails does not know how to handle it.  Looks like they have added this to Rails 5! (https://github.com/johnnaegle/rails_weak_etags/issues/1)

Answer (score 3):

middleware:

```
class WeakEtagMiddleware
  def initialize(app)
    @app = app
  end

  def call(env)
    # make request etags "strong"
    etag = env['HTTP_IF_NONE_MATCH']
    if etag && etag =~ /^W\//
      env['HTTP_IF_NONE_MATCH'] = etag[2..-1]
    end

    status, headers, body = @app.call(env)

    # make response etags "weak"
    etag = headers['ETag']
    if etag && etag !~ /^W\//
      headers['ETag'] = "W/#{etag}"
    end

    [status, headers, body]
  end
end
```

plus add middleware

```
Rails.application.config.middleware.insert_before(Rack::ETag, WeakEtagMiddleware)
```

plus unit tests

```
context WeakEtagMiddleware do
  let(:backend) { Rack::ConditionalGet.new(Rack::ETag.new(lambda { |env| [env["status"] || 200, {}, ["XXX"]] })) }
  let(:app) { WeakEtagMiddleware.new(backend) }
  let(:expected_digest_1) { "bc9189406be84ec297464a514221406d" }
  let(:env) { {"REQUEST_METHOD" => "GET"} }

  should "converts etags to weak" do
    status, headers, body = app.call(env)
    assert_equal %{W/"#{expected_digest_1}"}, headers["ETag"]
    assert_equal status, 200
  end

  should "not add etags to responses without etag" do
    status, headers, body = app.call(env.merge("status" => 400))
    refute headers["ETag"]
    assert_equal status, 400
  end

  should "recognize weak ETags" do
    status, headers, body = app.call(env.merge("HTTP_IF_NONE_MATCH" => %{W/"#{expected_digest_1}"}))
    assert_equal status, 304
  end

  should "not recognize invalid ETags" do
    status, headers, body = app.call(env.merge("HTTP_IF_NONE_MATCH" => %{W/"something-not-fresh"}))
    assert_equal status, 200
  end
end
```

plus integration tests

```
require_relative "../helpers/test_helper"

class WeakEtagsTest < ActionController::IntegrationTest
  class TestController < ActionController::Base
    def auto
      render :text => "XXX"
    end

    def fresh
      if stale? :etag => "YYY"
        render :text => "XXX"
      end
    end
  end

  additional_routes do
    get '/test/weak_etags/:action', :controller => 'weak_etags_test/test'
  end

  fixtures :accounts, :users

  context "weak etags" do
    let(:expected_digest_1) { "bc9189406be84ec297464a514221406d" }
    let(:expected_digest_2) { "fd7c5c4fdaa97163ee4ba8842baa537a" }

    should "auto adds weak etags" do
      get "/test/weak_etags/auto"
      assert_equal "XXX", @response.body
      assert_equal %{W/"#{expected_digest_1}"}, @response.headers["ETag"]
    end

    should "adds weak etags through fresh_when" do
      get "/test/weak_etags/fresh"
      assert_equal "XXX", @response.body
      assert_equal %{W/"#{expected_digest_2}"}, @response.headers["ETag"]
    end

    should "recognize auto-added ETags" do
      get "/test/weak_etags/auto", {}, {"HTTP_IF_NONE_MATCH" => %{W/"#{expected_digest_1}"}}
      assert_response :not_modified
    end

    should "recognize fresh ETags" do
      get "/test/weak_etags/fresh", {}, {"HTTP_IF_NONE_MATCH" => %{W/"#{expected_digest_2}"}}
      assert_response :not_modified
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: This worked to add weak etags, but nginx still doesn't support weak e-tags (April 2014). Maybe in 1.7.x says one of the authors: forum.nginx.org/read.php?29,249380,249423#msg-249423)

Comment: I used this as an initializer instead:  Rails.application.config.middleware.insert_before(Rack::ConditionalGet, WeakEtagMiddleware)  This lets requests without explicit etags have them automatically added by the middleware based on the response body.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like Rack::ETag will use weak-etags in the future:

- https://github.com/rack/rack/issues/681
  https://github.com/rack/rack/commit/12528d4567d8e6c1c7e9422fee6cd8b43c4389bf

Answer (score 1):

Here's an alternative that avoids making any changes in your application server. This directive  converts all etags returned by your application to weak etags before they get stripped from the response. Put it inside your inside your nginx config:

```
location / {
  add_header ETag "W/$sent_http_ETAG";
}
```

I've checked that this works with nginx 1.7.6.